# Maintain default values for parameter when switching between reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I know this is might sound peculiar but I couldn't find any reference to figure this out.

I have a report with `GroupID` as parameter that get a list of values from a secondary dataset. The default value is defined to be **(select All)**.

Now the report is a pie chart and by clicking on one of the "pies" you directed to a drill down report.

Now the problem is when I wish to go back to the main report. For some reason the default value for `GroupID` parameter is gone, and no data displayed.

I tried the following:

- pass the GroupID parameter to the second report and pass it back to the main report - because the parameter is multi values allowed I couldn't pass all the values, instead I can pass `=Parameters!GroupID.Value(0)` (I tried manually to pass `=Parameters!GroupID.Value` but again, no GO.
- not to pass any parameters between the reports - no GO.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is this only an issue if the default **(select all)** is altered or any time?

Comment: It only occur when **(select all)** is checked, if I select specific value it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can pass multi values  from one report to another

> pass the GroupID parameter to the second report and pass it back to
>   the main report - because the parameter is multi values allowed I
>   couldn't pass all the values, instead I can pass
>   =Parameters!GroupID.Value(0) (I tried manually to pass =Parameters!GroupID.Value but

Follow this scenario

**Report 1**

Parameter: OrganizationlID

Setting:

- Set as multi values
- Get values from query (Dataset)
- Default values get values from query (Dataset)

**Report 2**

Parameter: OrganizationlID (exactly the same name)

Setting:
 - Set as multi values
 - Get values from query (Dataset)
 - **No Default**

**Transitions between the reports**

I putted a `Textbox` on the report body and configure it on click to navigate to "Report 2"

I passed the parameter as follows:

```
=Parameters!OrganizationalID.Value
```

[image: Report 1 screenshot]

In the second report i got **all** the values selected in the parameter

In that report i have a "Textbox" (back) and i configure it to go to the first report
I passed the parameter as follows:

```
=Parameters!OrganizationalID.Value
```

Note that if you make some changes in the parameter you have to click on the "View Report" button, so that the values in the parameters will be saved in the session.

[image: Report 2 screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As a work around you could add a link back to the main report with the current reports value. This will however cause the report to run again.

Nice question, I've never had this issue and good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your support :) My issue with passing the secondary report's values, is that the main report will present different data compared to the initial display. My second thought was to create a second dataset in the DD report which will generate GroupID list and to pass it back to the main report - but the I figure that I still cannot pass multy values parameter when the **(select all)** value is defined.

Comment: If you make the DD reports parameter an exact copy of the main there is no reason the DD can't simply retrieve the main and then feed it back without manipulation. Be sure to add an action that supplies the parameter back see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207031.aspx

Comment: Hy, thx for your answer, but I still didn't figure how can I pass **(select all)** value in the parameter - SSRS let me only pass specific parameter index (e.g. `=Parameters!GroupID.Value(0)`)

Comment: You can do this by removing the `(0)` as long as the receiving parameter is set to multi-value. Is this set for both?

Comment: Yep, but I will double check it and let you know, Thank you.